# How to handle role dependencies execution in Ansible Playbooks

Tags: ansible

I have started an Ansible Collection with the different roles needed to install an application server for our application. Currently the roles are split as `wildfly`, `mysql`, `elasticsearch`, `mongodb`, etc...

Since multiple roles (to install WildFly and ElasticSearch in my case) also need Java to be installed and configured, I split the tasks related to Java into its own `java` role and added the `java` role into the roles dependencies in `roles/[wildfly,elasticsearch]/meta/main.yml`.

```
dependencies:
  - role: java
```

In the playbook I now have:

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: my_collection.bootstrap

- hosts: elasticsearch
  roles:
    - role: my_collection.elasticsearch

- hosts: wildfly
  roles:
    - role: my_collection.wildfly
```

And during the execution, the hosts will automatically also install Java where needed.

The problem I now have is how to handle the duplicate execution of `java` tasks if an host is assigned both `wildfly` and `elasticsearch`. The tasks related to the install are not causing any problems but there are tasks that are taking longer because they need to check the current state and apply changes only if needed. I would thus prefer to only apply the tasks from this role once.

Is there a way to ignore duplicate roles on a single host ? Or perhaps I missed a better way to organize the roles to avoid this problem ?

Comment: My "solution" to this was to take dependency handling away from ansible, as (in my opinion) ansible does not handle them properly in any case. I'm trying to design roles with as few dependencies as possible and then I use `include_role` to run roles in the correct order. This is my workaround, I don't say it is good, but it is possible. I'd be very interested in the "right" way to do it, though.

Comment: This could work if all your child roles were played inside the same play but you would then have to put conditionals on each role depending on the host you are playing on, kind of reinventing the play host target... My experience with role dependency: I had many in my beginnings, I only kept a few (like creating a in-house customization on top of a publicly available role). For your current issue, I now simply add a preflight check "java is available" and fail with a message "java vx.y.z needed please install (hint: see my_java_role)". The user can then install it however he wants.

Answer (score 0):

While using `meta/main.yml` dependencies is possible, in practice it's better to loosen up on this ;-) Your Java role can just as well be stated just above its dependents in the playbook with a comment that it's supposed to go first. That saves refactoring all the dependents when trying another Java. Loose coupling is helpful in the long term. You can declare `roles/requirements.yml` as a straight list, easier to audit too.